# Assign class to first image

Tags: javascript, css

I've got the following javascript in-place to attach a class to the first instance of the img tag in my post content. But simply not working at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var entries = document.querySelectorAll('.post-content');
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            var firstImage = $(entries[i].querySelectorAll('img:first')[0]);
            firstImage.addClass('post-first-img');
        }
    });
</script>
```

My class which is setup ready for when the above works

```
.main-content .post-content .post-first-img  { min-width: 890px; }
```

I tried with this already too, didn't work.

```
.main-content .post-content img.post-first-img  { min-width: 890px; }
```

Live URL: http://highways.designlocker.co.uk/hitex-has-innovative-solutions-for-road-marking-and-surfacing/

Comment: Could you say something like `$('.post-content').each(function(){ $(this).find('img:eq(0)').addClass('post-first-img'); });`?

Comment: `Element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]` or `$('.post-content img')[0]`. Why use `querySelectorAll` if using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because there is no `:first` selector in normal CSS. It only exist in jQuery, but you use it with `querySelectorAll` which relies on native CSS selectors.

Just removing it should work.

---

But since you already use jQuery why not use

```
$('.post-content').each(function(){
  $(this).find('img:first').addClass('post-first-img');
});
```

Comment: Or just `entries[i].querySelector('img')` which returns the first matching element.

Comment: Not working for me right now but just seen some console error, trying to figure that out now too, anychance you are able to see the console error pointing to the code I copied in of yours?

Comment: @JordanC26 you have called the `.noConflict()` method so you do not have access to the `$`. replace it with `jQuery`

Comment: Hmm, don't actually remember doing that, or even see it right now. Mind telling me where/how you found this, I'd rather be able to use $ as normal.

Comment: @JordanC26 you include jquery 1.11.1 at the top (*in that file at the end it calls the `.noConflict()`*). Then you include jquery v2.1.1 and after the mailchimp registration you do `$ymce = jQuery.noConflict();` which removes the `$` again..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of your elements are wrapped in `<p>` tags, so this makes all images that are only-children of those p tags have an index of 0.
What you need to do is target the first `<p>` element and apply the class to its first image element.

Something along the lines of:

```
$('.post-content p:first-child img:first-of-type').addClass('post-first-img');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing native DOM methods with jQuery methods, which can lead to some confusion. The selector `:first` is part of jQuery, and you are using it from a DOM function.

Since you are already using jQuery, I suggest that you convert all the `querySelectorAll` calls into jQuery calls:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var entries = $('.post-content');
    entries.each(function() {
        var firstImage = $(this).find('img:first');
        firstImage.addClass('post-first-img');
    });
});
```

Note: the above code could be made shorter, I just kept it in a similar format to the original one so that you can better understand it.